# Eclipse not recognizing imports of generated classes in same project

Tags: java, import, apache-camel, camel-cxf

I have camel project to invoke soap service using CXF. There are generated classes from WSDL but beans cannot import these classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Project properties - Java build path - Source and add folder where are generated classes.